# How to select the last 2 observations by group?

Tags: sas

How can I select the last 2 observations by group in SAS? I know the statements (first. and last.) but this only select the last of first one observation, I need the 2 last ones by group after the sort.

Example:
My data:

```
    NAME  DATE 
    BOB  24/05/2013
    BOB  12/06/2012
    BOB  19/10/2011
    BOB  05/02/2010
    BOB  05/01/2009
    CARL 15/05/2011
    LOUI 15/01/2014
    LOUI 15/05/2013
    LOUI 15/05/2012
```

I need this result

```
    NAME  DATE 
    BOB  24/05/2013
    BOB  12/06/2012
    CARL 15/05/2011
    LOUI 15/01/2014
    LOUI 15/05/2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `first.` variable in the following way using [enumeration within groups.](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/enumerate.htm)

As you would like to retain the 2 most recent records for each name, proceed by sorting them as follows:

```
PROC SORT DATA = mydata;
    BY name DESCENDING date;
RUN;

DATA recentObs;
    SET mydata;
    count + 1;
    BY name DESCENDING date;
    IF FIRST.name THEN count=1;
    IF count<=2 THEN OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

You need to think about how to handle cases if same name can have > 1records on the same day.